# How to create visible sections in Visualforce

Tags: visualforce

I need to create a vf page that shows both contact and account information. I would like to structure this data into sections, i.e. have a section for account and a section for contact. I used apex pageblocksection:

```
<apex:pageBlocksection id="section1"  title="Account Fields" columns="2" collapsible="false" showheader="false">
```

I want the section to say "Account Fields", but it doesn't seem to work. Any ideas? Tia

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have `showHeader="false"` the header is where the title would be displayed, try setting that to true.

Answer (score 1):

Remove `showheader="false"`. The [documentation](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_pageBlockSection.htm) notes about this flag:

> A Boolean value that specifies whether the page block section title is
>   displayed. If set to true, the header is displayed. If not specified,
>   this value defaults to true.